# How to reload or update UI in .Net MAUI, when culture has been changed?

Tags: c#, maui

I have a button with a clicked event that triggers the following:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("da");
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK", false);
```

Below the button, I have a Label, with the text assigned as a value in an .resx-file.
The solution has various labels, on various pages, that are all set with .resx-files.

**When I click the button, how can I update all pages to switch to the new culture?**

Edit: My main problem here was refreshing the app/triggering the new culture. See that accepted answer for how I solved this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement .NET MAUI localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315229/how-to-implement-net-maui-localization)

Comment: I'll expand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up doing it this way:

First, a button has the folllowing Clicked-event in the code-behind:

```
private void ChosenLanguageTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    App.CultureString = new CultureInfo("culture-code", false);
    SetUIMethod(App.CultureString);
    Preferences.Set("language", App.CultureString.Name);
    Reset();
}
```

In my "SetUIMethod", I have the following  instructions:

```
    public void SetUIMethod(CultureInfo culture)
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
}
```

So the new culture is set, and lastly, I call Reset(), which does the following:

```
void Reset()
{
    (Application.Current as App).MainPage.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
    {
        (Application.Current as App).MainPage = new AppShell();
    });
}
```

I will look into Serge Misnik's answer at some point, but this is fine for now.

In regards to keeping language when the app is closed and re-opened, I used Gerald Versluis' guide [here](https://youtu.be/_ZFXk3vbxwQ?t=497)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of what your localization process looks like, but if it's in a standard way that can be found on the internet and you have set the CultureInfo to the localization manager, then you just need to restart the app by

```
        (Application.Current as App).MainPage = new AppShell();
```

If there is still a problem, please, just elaborate on your problem and your localization process/solution a little bit more.

Comment: I'll elaborate my question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting AppShell is bad idea and may lead to numerous bugs. I've used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cf4sXULR7os) solution and it works great. Basically, you'd need a localization manager and a markup extension:

```
public class LocalizationManager : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private static readonly Lazy<LocalizationManager> _instance = new(()=> new LocalizationManager());
    private LocalizationManager()
    {
        Properties.Resources.Culture = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture;
    }
    public static LocalizationManager Instance => _instance.Value;

    public object this[string resourceKey] => Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey, Properties.Resources.Culture) ?? string.Empty;

    public void SetCulture(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Properties.Resources.Culture =
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture=
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture =
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture =
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture =
        culture;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(string.Empty));
    }
}
```

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Key))]
public class LocalizationExtension : IMarkupExtension<BindingBase>
{
    public string Key { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public BindingBase ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
        new Binding
        {
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = $"[{Key}]",
            Source = LocalizationManager.Instance,
        };

    object IMarkupExtension.ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
}
```

Add `public LocalizationManager Localize => LocalizationManager.Instance;` to your model. You could do it other way, this is just an example.

Adjust your xaml like
`<Label Text="{Binding Localize[SamplePage_Loading]}" />` where `SamplePage_Loading` is key of resource.

To change current language just call `LocalizationManager.Instance.SetCulture(newCultureOfChoice);`

Answer (score 0):

The approach with setup Cultures within Dispatcher.Dispatch method helped me in my MAUI app. Setup new AppShell inside dispatcher method made the app completely stuck.

```
App.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
(Application.Current as App).MainPage.Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
{
    CultureInfo cultureInfo = new(culture, false);
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
});
```