# How to solve the problem about loading resx resources dll on iOS (.NET MAUI)

Tags: .net, maui, resx

Background:

I want to do the localizations feature on my .NET MAUI app. I follow this video (https://youtu.be/cf4sXULR7os) to do that.

[image]

In the iOS simulator, the localization feature and loading the resources.dll is running preferably. (like the following)

[image]

But once I deploy it to my physical iPhone device, the feature does not work and outputs the following message when I change the language.

> Language is Traditional Chinese
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.410 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh-TW, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.411 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh-Hant, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.413 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.415 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh-TW, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.416 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh-Hant, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:01.417 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=zh, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> Language is English
> 2023-07-12 01:10:02.041 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:02.042 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:02.044 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en-US, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.
> 2023-07-12 01:10:02.046 Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[645:115119] Could not resolve assembly TestApp.resources, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=en, PublicKeyToken=null. Details: Could not load file or assembly '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/1F073A32-D7F4-4009-81C6-D12526416BC2/Documents/TestApp.content/TestApp.resources.dll' or one of its dependencies.

So, I checked the app folder on the "Files" app and confirmed there is no ".resources.dll" in it.

[image]
[image]

Why are there no ".resources.dll" output and deployed when installed, and how can I solve them? Because as I know, language resources (resx->dll) should place in a sub-folder like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/71315229/199364

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update .NET 8.0 will fix the issue.