# .NET MAUI Per-app language preference on Android

Tags: android, maui, maui-android

In Android, a newer feature is allowing users to [change language on a per-app basis](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) .

Is there any way to do this in .NET MAUI? The AndroidManifest.xml is editable, but I don't think build.gradle is. If the build.gradle file isn't possible to edit, then I guess it isn't possible.

The only close things I've found is https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/b423ff68a6d11230bb493c3cb0633ff2a9c37b20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to change any Gradle files to make **Per-app language preferences** work.

Just follow this steps and it will work for you:

1. Add **Platforms/Android/Resources/xml/locales_config.xml** with languages for App settings (Build action should be "AndroidResource"):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<locale-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <locale android:name="en-US"/>
    <locale android:name="en-GB"/>
    <locale android:name="fr"/>
</locale-config>
```

2. Edit **AndroidManifest.xml**, by adding a line to point to locales_config:

```xml
<manifest>
    ...
    <application
        ...
        android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3. Add Resources.resx files (I prefer to add them to **Resources/Strings/AppResources.resx**)
4. Use your AppResources.resx in any view:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:strings="clr-namespace:PerAppLanguagePreference.Resources.Strings"
             x:Class="PerAppLanguagePreference.MainPage">
             ...
             <Label
                Text="{Static strings:AppResources.HelloWorld}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
             ...
</ContentPage>
```

After app language change in Settings, according AppResources.xx.resx will be used.

Comment: Perfect! You are correct. When I read https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages#gradle-config I thought I also had to edit the gradle. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/localization#localize-text) for MAUI. It is just as Per-app language preferences. It's all about how you implement language conversion. Localization is the process of adapting an app to meet the specific language or cultural requirements of a target market.

More information about [How to implement .NET MAUI localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71315229/how-to-implement-net-maui-localization).

Comment: This isn't about localising itself. There is additional configurations you can do in an Android app that let you change the app's language in the system settings.