# Unable to switch app language/locale at runtime in a .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid Application

Tags: localization, blazor, maui, cultureinfo, maui-blazor

I'm currently developing a .NET MAUI Blazor hybrid application ([GitHub repo here](https://github.com/Technical-Publications-Bombardier/CsdbMigration)) and I've encountered an issue with changing the locale at runtime.

| Component | Version |
| --- | --- |
| .NET [image] SDK | 8.0.200-preview.23624.5 |
| IDE | Microsoft Visual Studio [image] Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.9.0 Preview 4.0 |

My application *aims* (but fails) to support multiple languages, and I want users to be able to switch between these languages at runtime in [the `Settings` page](https://github.com/Technical-Publications-Bombardier/CsdbMigration/blob/81f1295f20b0d0f87141dc5d7e4ad96e1682fd57/Components/Pages/Settings.razor). However, no matter what approach I try, the result is always the same: The application receives the language request, but the app culture never changes. My debug output always shows:

```bash
OnSubmitLanguage: fr  # This is the language I chose
Current Culture: en-CA  # This is my computer's locale
Current UI Culture: en-US  # This is the default app locale
Thread Current Culture: en-CA
Thread Current UI Culture: en-US
```

To achieve this, I've tried several approaches:

1. **Traditional `AppRes` Approach**: Initially, I tried using the [traditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/localization?view=net-maui-8.0) [`AppRes` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71796636/1757756) for localization. However, this did not allow me to change the locale at runtime. Although I choose to switch languages, the app culture (and hence, language) never changes:

| [Settings page](https://github.com/Technical-Publications-Bombardier/CsdbMigration/blob/81f1295f20b0d0f87141dc5d7e4ad96e1682fd57/Components/Pages/Settings.razor) Language Selector | [Settings page](https://github.com/Technical-Publications-Bombardier/CsdbMigration/blob/81f1295f20b0d0f87141dc5d7e4ad96e1682fd57/Components/Pages/Settings.razor) Save Button | Result in the [debug window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image: Language Selector] | [image: Save button after language selected] | [image: language choice has no effect] |

2. **`Localizer` Approach**: Next, I tried using the newer `IStringLocalizer<T>` service, which is recommended for localization in .NET 6 and onwards. Despite setting the culture as shown below, the UI did not update to reflect the new culture.

   ```cs
   public void OnSubmitLanguage(EventArgs args)
   {
       Debug.Print($"OnSubmitLanguage: {SelectedLanguage}");
       Debug.Print($"Current Culture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Current UI Culture: {CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Thread Current Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Thread Current UI Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");
       var newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(SelectedLanguage);
       CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
   }
   ```
3. **Multilingual App Toolkit Approach**: I also tried using [the Multilingual App Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-mat), which is a contemporary recommendation for localization in .NET applications. However, this approach also did not result in the desired behavior.
4. **Cookie Setting Approach**: Finally, I tried storing the selected culture in a cookie. For this, I created a [`CookieService` class](https://github.com/Technical-Publications-Bombardier/CsdbMigration/blob/81f1295f20b0d0f87141dc5d7e4ad96e1682fd57/Services/CookieService.cs) and used it to set the culture cookie. However, this also did not result in the UI updating to the new culture.

   ```cs
   public void OnSubmitLanguage(EventArgs args)
   {
       Debug.Print($"OnSubmitLanguage: {SelectedLanguage}");
       Debug.Print($"Current Culture: {CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Current UI Culture: {CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Thread Current Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture}");
       Debug.Print($"Thread Current UI Culture: {Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture}");
       var newCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(SelectedLanguage);
       CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
       // Store the selected culture in a cookie
       var cookieValue = CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(newCulture));
       cookieService.SetCookie(".AspNetCore.Culture", cookieValue, 365);
   }
   ```

Despite trying these different approaches, I'm still unable to change the locale at runtime. The `CurrentCulture` and `CurrentUICulture` remain unchanged after the method is called, as indicated by the debug prints.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which Visual Studio version do you use? Visual Studio 2022 or Visual Studio 2022 Preview?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT I  am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.9.0 Preview 4.0

Comment: For the Traditional AppRes Approach, did there occur any errors after selected the language?

Comment: @SeanHe-MSFT, no, there were no errors. It successfully retrieves the default strings from the `AppRes` helper. The problem is that it only takes the default strings (the locale never changes even when I try to change it at runtime).